# Draw Rectangle and see it on batch without any texture

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

I am making a rectangle :

```
rect = new Rectangle();
rect.x = 40;
rect.y = 100;
rect.setSize(100,100);
```

and then also drawing some texture on the position of rectangle like:

```
batch.draw(myTexture, rect.x , rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
```

Now what i want to do is also see the shape of rectangle like i must see some boundary so that i can see my rectangle boundary as well as my texture. And i need this for debugging purposes as the texture is complex like somewhere the background is transparent so i want to remove the collision from those places and that is why i am thinking if i could see both the rectangles and the sprite it would be great.

Although i tried doing this:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
shapeRenderer.rect(0,0,100,100);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

I thought the above code would help me draw the texture as well as see the rectangle but turns out i could see only the rectangle's boundary and not the texture.

Here is the output:

[image: pass the bars: a ball game]

In the image , you can see a red rectangle and that is where i was trying to debug my bar (a bar of yellow color was also supposed to be shown here) but my yellow doesn't appear as this red-boundary rectangle overlapped my bar.

To be clear, i want to see the shapeRenderer right above the texture and be able to see the both of them

Comment: Have you tried using both, First drawing the texture with the normal SpriteBatch then using the ShapeRenderer to draw the rectangle?

Comment: yes i have tried doing both and shapeRenderer completely overwrites the drawing texture with batch and that happens because shapeRenderer code is written after drawing the texture to batch but since i am using line ShapeType in shapeRenderer i thought i might see both of them but apparently does not turn out like so.

Comment: You may need to enable blending before any draw calls by the shape renderer to allow transparency.

Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
render shape
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

Comment: I have already done that. Just let me add the output screenshot.

Comment: I tested your code and the image is shown with a single pixel border line as expected.

Comment: Do you see the texture as well as the shapeRenderer? Try pasting a texture in your assets folder and see if you see them both. To be clear, i want to see the shapeRenderer right above the texture and be able to see the both of them.

Comment: I just created the textures at runtime with pixmap instead of messing with file loading or making a new image, but yeah the image is drawn normally with spriteBatch and then the border is drawn with shapeRenderer and both show. Code for this is on pastebin (https://pastebin.com/HLAybUv8)

Comment: Make sure SpriteBatch and ShapeRenderer are using the same projection matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the answer,

As you know i wanted to appear a rectangle over my texture so that i could see both - my texture and my shapeRenderer shape but instead i could see only my shape and not the texture.

Problem was that What is was doing is i began the batch and inside that i wrote the code for drawing to the batch and also the code for drawing the shapeRenderer to the batch like this:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(texture,0,0,0,0);
shapeRenderer.begin();
shapeRenderer.rect(0,0,0,0);
shapeRenderer.end();
batch.end();
```

The above code replaces my texture as it can only draw one thing at the coordinates 0,0 so first it draws the texture at 0,0 and then the shaperenderer at 0,0.

The solution was:

To draw the shapeRenderer separately and not within the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()` like:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(texture,0,0,0,0);
batch.end();

shapeRenderer.begin();
shapeRenderer.rect(0,0,0,0);
shapeRenderer.end();
```